# azure-sdk-for-js - More than one account was found authenticated for this Client ID and Tenant ID

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sdk-js

Trying to login withClientSecretCredential using a service account

```
const { setLogLevel } = require("@azure/logger");
setLogLevel("verbose");

this.credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, secret,{
      loggingOptions: { allowLoggingAccountIdentifiers: true, enableUnsafeSupportLogging: true },
    } );
```

the authentication is failing due to this error

```
azure:identity:info ClientSecretCredential => More than one account was found authenticated for this Client ID and Tenant ID.
However, no "authenticationRecord" has been provided for this credential,
therefore we're unable to pick between these accounts.
A new login attempt will be requested, to ensure the correct account is picked.
To work with multiple accounts for the same Client ID and Tenant ID, please provide an "authenticationRecord" when initializing a credential to prevent this from happening.
azure:identity:info ClientSecretCredential => Silent authentication failed, falling back to interactive method.
```

Any suggestions?